# Should I build AD or AP on Azir?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've had a discussion with a friend earlier today on how to use the full potential of Azir's abilities and passive.

Some people play him full Attack Damage + CDR to profit from his passive 2% Attack Speed for every 1% CDR whereas others just want to play him as classic mage capitalizing on magic damage burst.

Am I wrong when I suggest to build AD and CDR on Azir? I'm thinking about a build similar to this:

Essence Reaver, The Black Cleaver, Zeke's Herald(or Zephyr - situational ), infinite edge, Trinity Force and Mercury's Treads boots.

Comment: the best way is try it out on your own... write a guide and wait for feedback. if you win everygame with this build then why not? what are you expecting as answers? your build doesnt really have that much CDR in it...

Comment: Azir's soldiers do not proc on-hit effects such as lifesteal or Black Cleaver's armor shred. They WILL proc spell effects like Rylai's slow and spell vamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build you've mentioned isn't really that viable on Azir. Mainly due to the fact that he scales purely with AP and not with AD. While you could still attack with your basic attacks, his full potential lies in his Soldiers which scale **only** with AP.

So you're better off buying Abilitypower, Cooldownreduction and maybe even Attackspeed (Nashors tooth is a great item on him) since you will not only deal more damage in teamfights but you will also be safer while using your sand soldiers to attack.

Now if you build AD + Cooldown Reduction + Attackspeed (like the build you suggested), you will attack slightly faster with your soldiers but your soldiers won't deal any damage (simply 170 Damage at lvl 18). If you build AP + Cooldown Reduction + Attackspeed your soldiers will attack fast and they will also deal a huge amount of damage (170 + 70% of your AP at lvl 18).

Comment: there are too many champions that have abilities that only scale with ap and despite that they are built as tanks (leona, elise etc...) they consider the utility aspect of the champion more than his abilities scaling with ap or ad... this is why i prefer profiting from passive and taking advantage from the utility of the soldiers + ult (engage escape in the team figths) rather than play it pure mage..

Comment: @KarouiHaythem yeah that is why you have to buy Cooldownreduction and Attackspeed aswell. But building him as AD is basically useless. Also there is no utility in buying Lifesteal or crit since the attacks of his soldiers count as spell, not as an autoattack.

Comment: does the cooldwn reduction increase only the soldiers' attack speed or azir's auto attack speed is increased too ?

Comment: @KarouiHaythem It increases the attack speed of Azir, but his soldiers have the same attackspeed as Azir (so technically it increases the attackspeed of both). I'll try to clarify my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

> When Azir attacks an enemy in a soldier's range, the soldier attacks instead of Azir

This scales with attackspeed because the faster Azir attacks, the faster the soldiers attack. The damage of the soldiers scales with AP.

So i would build him AP + CDR because all his abilitys scale with AP.

Comment: if you have already played azir i think you would have noticed how easy is to dodge his soldiers... in the other side azir can use his soldiers to run or engage in a fight ... and once playing as adc he can also use his ulti to push away bruisers in the team fight...

Comment: @KarouiHaythem I don't understand what you want to do. From what I understand, Azir soldiers will do zero damage, the Q will do zero damage, the ulti will do zero damage. Only Azir autoattacks will do more damage with an AD build. Why dont you build him as mage and play the utility so that your adc can do the damage? Just like an Oriana?